# How to specify variables in Format statement

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am trying to print a tree with the help of "format" and a variables. But couldn't figure out how to pass in variable and get an output in a generalized form. The below code works for a particular example but not for any tree.

I used hard coded approach for getting the horizontal spacing right using the if statement as below. But i want to just pass-in the variable "count" which contains the height of the tree, and get a output directly.

```
    if (count .eq. 9) then
        write(6,9) t%element
            9   format (t12,I3)
    else if (count .eq. 8) then
        write(6,8) t%element
            8   format (t9,I3)
    else if (count .eq. 7) then
        write(6,7) t%element
            7   format (t6,I3)
    else 
        write(6,6) t%element
            6   format (t3,I3)
    end if
```

The result you get is like this

---

```
 1
     2
 3
         4
 5
     6
 7
```

Comment: I suggest to ignore the accepted answer in the duplicate. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372220/variable-format-statement-when-porting-from-intel-to-gnu-gfortran

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to have the format identifier as a string, like this:

```
character(len=len("(T02, I3)")) :: fmt

write(fmt, '("(T", I2.2, ", I3)")') count  ! if count=2, fmt will be "(T02, I3)"
write(*, fmt) t%element
```

Comment: I am getting a compiler error as **this**,      Error #6899: First non-blank character in a character type format specifier must be a left parenthesis.   ['"(T", I2.2, ", I3)")']

Comment: You're right, I was missing an open parenthesis. Try it now.

Comment: Yeah it works, **thanks**; you were again missing a **'('** . But i figured it out. So according to the above code, the spacing between them characters of the tree is 1 position. The reason for this is because of Specifying 'T' instead of T3 or T4. But if i change T to T3 it shows error in the final compilation output. I am just curious of how to increase the spacing it?

Comment: The `count` variable gives the number of spaces. You can say `write(fmt, ...) 2*count+1` if you want 1, 3, 5, etc spaces.