# Output formatting with the write statement via gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I used to the Intel fortran compiler which supports using the `<n>` extension like

```
write(*, '(<n>(2I4))') (i, 2*i, i=1,n)
```

To illustrate, I give a `s1_fprint.f90` subroutine as follows

```
subroutine fprint(name,bb)

IMPLICIT NONE
character(len=*), intent(in) :: name
real, intent(in) :: bb(:,:)
integer :: column=10
integer i,j,k,m,n

n = size(bb,1)
m = size(bb,2)

write(*,'(1a)')name
do k=0,m/column-1
    write(*, '(1x,<column>i16)')(i,i=k*column+1,(k+1)*column)
    write(*,'(1i10,<column>f)')(i,(bb(i,j),j=k*column+1,(k+1)*column),i=1,n)
    write(*,'(/)')
end do
if(mod(m,column)/=0)then
    write(*, '(1x,<m-m/column*column>i16)')(i,i=m/column*column+1,m)
    write(*,'(1i10,<m-m/column*column>f)')(i,(bb(i,j),j=m/column*column+1,m),i=1,n)
    write(*,'(/)')
endif

end subroutine fprint
```

Now, I change the Intel fortran compiler to gfortran, then I test (`t1_useSur.f90`)
above subroutine in gfortran as follows:

```
program main

implicit none
real :: A(2,3) = reshape([1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 6.7], [2,3])

call fprint('A',A)

end program main
```

which should show us something like

```
A
            1              2              3
    1      1.2000000      3.4000001      5.5999999
    2      2.3000000      4.5000000      6.6999998
```

However, in gfortran compiler when I run

```
gfortran t1_useSur.f90 s1_fprint.f90 -o out
./out
```

there are many errors as

```
.\s1_fprint.f90:14.17:

    write(*, '(1x,<column>i16)')(i,i=k*column+1,(k+1)*column)
                1
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
.\s1_fprint.f90:15.19:

    write(*,'(1i10,<column>f)')(i,(bb(i,j),j=k*column+1,(k+1)*column),i=1,n)
                1
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
.\s1_fprint.f90:19.17:

    write(*, '(1x,<m-m/column*column>i16)')(i,i=m/column*column+1,m)
                1
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
.\s1_fprint.f90:20.19:

    write(*,'(1i10,<m-m/column*column>f)')(i,(bb(i,j),j=m/column*column+1,m),i=
                1
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
```

Since the `<n>` extension is not supported by gfortran, how can fix these problems?

Comment: Regarding your previous supplemental question, `m/column-1` would be less than zero, giving no passes through the loop.  You will want simply `m-1`.

Comment: I will try it. Tks for your help @francescalus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Near* dupe [Variable format statement when porting from Intel to GNU gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372220/variable-format-statement-when-porting-from-intel-to-gnu-gfortran)

For the 1-dim cases like `(i,i=...)` :

- If you have (or get) a version of gfortran that supports F08, which browsing https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ appears to be around 4.6.4 up, use `*` as the count like `(1x,*i16)`
- Otherwise, use the old-as-<strike>the-hills</strike>F77 trick: since format repetitions or items 'beyond' the data list are ignored, just use a repetition count that is at least as big as the data will ever be (but not more than HUGE(0)) here `(1x,10i16)` is actually enough but something like `(1x,999i16)` makes it much more obvious
- or if you like extra work, do on-the-fly like the 2-dim case below

For the 2-dim cases like `(i,(bb(i,j),j=...),i=...)` which currently use format looping to insert record breaks either:

- reduce to 1-dim by making the record breaks into separate WRITEs:

```
    do i=...
        write(*,'(1i10,*f)') i,(bb(i,j),j=...)
    end do !i
```

- generate the correct count on-the-fly:

```
    character(len=20) fmt
    ...
    write(fmt,'(a,i0,a)') '(1i10,', numcols_expression, 'f)'
    write(*, trim(fmt)) (i,(bb(i,j),j=...),i=...)
    ... or ...
    write(fmt,'(i0)') numcols_expression
    write(*, '(1i10,'//trim(fmt)//'f)') (i,bb(i,j),j=...),i=...)
```

PS: you don't actually need `1i10` just `i10`, but I left it for consistency. Also rather than a loop for the full chunks then an if for the partial chunk, which have to be kept in sync, I would probably do:

```
    do k=1,m,column
      l=min(k+column-1,m)
      ... print chunk for i=k,l (numcols is l-k+1) ...
    end do !k
```

Comment: Tks!  I test the code following your hints and please see my re-edited contents above. There are still some problems with it. BTW,  the `gfortran --version` command on the PC gives `GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.3 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a new question - just ask an appropriate new question. It makes everything much easier for other to search

Comment: Got it and sorry for that. Tks for reminding me of this @Ian Bush@Ian Bush